# Java Oracle connection pooling - Closed Connection exception

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, connection-pooling

This post is intended to be less of a question and more a confirmation that I'm doing things correctly. I've seen many similar posts but I'm not sure I fully understand everything that's been said.

The problem is that, after a certain amount of time, I get an exception when trying to establish a connection to my oracle database. (I'm using Tomcat 6.0 and Spring)

Previously I had the following configuration:

```
private PoolDataSource poolDataSource = null;

public MainDAOImpl(String url, String username, String password)
        throws Exception
{
    poolDataSource = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();

    try
    {
        poolDataSource.setConnectionFactoryClassName("oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource");
        poolDataSource.setURL(url);
        poolDataSource.setUser(username);
        poolDataSource.setPassword(password);
    }
    catch( SQLException e )
    {
        ...
    }
}

public List<Object> getValues(String query)
{
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

    try
    {
        connection = poolDataSource.getConnection();
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);

        ...
    }
    catch( SQLException e )
    {
        ...
    }
    finally
    {
        //close connections
    }
}
```

However, sometimes the `preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);` threw an SQLException with a "Closed Exception" message.

It's important to note that the MainDAOImpl's constructor gets called only once per server restart (it's dependency injected via Spring).

I've recently changed my setup like so:

```
private DataSource dataSource = null;

public MainDAOImpl()
        throws Exception
{
    try
    {
        Context initContext = new InitialContext();
        Context envContext = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
        dataSource = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/myOracleConn");
    }
    catch( NamingException e )
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

and `poolDataSource.getConnection()` to `dataSource.getConnection()`.

I've also added the following Resource to my Context in Tomcat:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/myOracleConn" auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
          url="<myURL>"
          username="<myUsername>" password="<myPassword>"
          maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWaith="-1" />
```

This basically follows http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html word-for-word.

Everything seems to be working. My question is, will these changes solve my closed connection problem or is there something different I need to do?

Thanks,

B.J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you are using Spring for dependency injection, I would recommend that you also use DI to inject the DAO's dependencies into it.

In other words, your DAO should have a DataSource injected into it, rather than the DAO implementation knowing either 1) what type of DataSource to construct or 2) how and where to look it up in JNDI. Spring [can handle JNDI lookups](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-jee) for you.

I'd also recommend using Spring's [JdbcTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-core), as it makes for a great wrapper over raw JDBC calls yourself.

Finally, the actual exception you are getting may just be because the database server is closing long-open connections. Not sure which connection pool implementation you are using, but in commons-dbcp there is [an option for a "validationQuery"](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html#validationQuery) which the pool will execute before returning a connection to verify the connection is still valid. I'm sure most other pools supply similar features, which I would recommend here - this way your DAO is never receiving stale connections from the pool.